# How to convert float to date format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, nsdate, nsformatter

I have a float value, what i need is convert my float to date. For example i have float 50,55, i want to put on a label value like this: 50 years 6 month 6 hours 6 mins 30,04 sec.

And i wonder how to make this label change every 0.01 second for change value. Please provide me solution to convert my float value to date format, any help would be appreciated.

This is code i use for create my float:

```
-(float)calculationResult{

    lifeTime = (kCountry +kEdu - kBirth - kSmo -kAlco+kDis+kHap+kDri+kMar)*kWei*kEnv*kSle;

    return lifeTime;
}
```

Comment: You want to what? Float isn't accurate enough for that. Years and months have different number of days and no one can see 100 values a second. Please tell me you don't want to display every 100th of a second. Have a look at the TimeSpan class.

Comment: My float is number of years, how this could be not enough? If you mean bissextile years i suppose all years are equal and have 365 days

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: One second is about 3e-08 years, that is beyond the precision of a float, you would need at least a double. - And how many days should one month have for your calculation?

Comment: Well, then i need to have only yyyy-mm-dd format, and maybe hours.

Comment: Enough? Accuracy, not range. Years isn't a problem, number of 100ths of second as a fraction of a second is 5.25 * e-10 ish. e-12 for 100ths.. DateTime as Double is NumberOfDaysSinceEpochStart.NumberOfSecondsSinceMidnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code splits the given number of "fractional years" into
years, month, days and hours. It makes the simplifying assumptions that every year
has 365 days, and that one month is exactly 1/12 of a year.

```
float tmp = lifeTime;
int years = tmp;
tmp =  (tmp - years) * 12.;
int months = tmp;
tmp = (tmp - months) * 365./12.;
int days = tmp;
tmp = (tmp - days) * 24.;
int hours = tmp;

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d years %d month %d days %d hours ",
                 years, months, days, hours];
```

To update a label regularly, you can use the `NSTimer` class (but updating every 1/100 second is much too often).